# Why is the positioning of the newline character before the string leading to it not getting printed?

Tags: c, sockets, newline

I am new to socket programming. I wrote a code for receiver:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<netinet/in.h>
#include<netinet/ip.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<unistd.h>

 int main()
{int ret= socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0);
  if (ret==-1)
   {printf("\nsocket creation fails");
    exit (0);}
  else
   printf("\nsocket creation succeeds");

 struct sockaddr_in sender;
 int port;
 printf("\nEnter port:");
 scanf("%d",&port);
 sender.sin_family= AF_INET;
 sender.sin_port=htons(port);
 sender.sin_addr.s_addr=INADDR_ANY;

 int ret1;
 ret1= bind(ret,(struct sockaddr *)&sender,sizeof(sender));

 if(ret1==-1)
 {printf("\nsocket binding fails");
  exit (0);}
 else
 printf("\nsocket binding succeeds");

 struct sockaddr_in receiver;
 char str[15]; 
 int addrlen=sizeof(receiver);

 while(1)
 {int rec=recvfrom(ret,str,sizeof(str),0,(struct sockaddr*)&receiver,&addrlen);
  printf("\nreceived");
  str[rec]='\0';
  if(strcmp(str,"exit")==0)
  break;

  if (rec==-1)
  {printf("\nrecvfrom fails");
  exit (0);}

  else
  {printf("\nrecv succeeds");
   printf("\n%s",str);}
  }

  close(ret);
  return 0;
  }
```

The output for this code prints `received` then `recv succeeds` on the next line, after which the cursor goes to the next line but does not print str. However in the next iteration of while, the older str value is printed before `received` and `recv succeeds`. This problem was solved when I used
`printf("%s\n",str)` instead of `printf("\n%s",str)`. Why is this happening?

Comment: Because `stdout` is, by default, "line buffered", ie... data is output line by line (and a line is defined as a sequence of chars including and terminated by an ENTER). Your best option is to terminate prints with `"\n"`; but you can try changing the buffering method of `stdout` with maybe [`setvbuf()`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.5.6) or force the output at anytime with [`fflush()`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.5.2)

Comment: Thank you! So it means that the OS doesn't print str because it treats the previously encountered "\n" as the end of str. Am I getting it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard output stream, `stdout`, is commonly line buffered when it is directed to a terminal. Per C 2018 7.21.3 3:

> … When a stream is *line buffered*, characters are intended to be transmitted to or from the host environment as a block when a new-line character is encountered. Furthermore, characters are intended to be transmitted as a block to the host environment when a buffer is filled, when input is requested on an unbuffered stream, or when input is requested on a line buffered stream that requires the transmission of characters from the host environment…

Thus, characters after a new-line character remain in the buffer (inside the computer’s memory, not displayed on the output device) until a new-line character is written, or you request input (as with `scanf`) on an associated input stream, or you explicitly request flushing of the buffer, or so much is written that the buffer is filled.

For this reason, it is bad practice to write `printf` statements using new-line characters at the beginnings, such as `"\nrecv succeeds"`. C was designed for output to have new-line characters at the ends of lines for common applications, such as `"recv succeeds\n"`.

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot!